# Multi-axis x with matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

My aim is to get something that looks like the image below:

[image]

For the moment I've tried to build it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

X = ['Class 1','Class 2','Class 3','Class 4', 'Class 5', 'Class 6', 'Class 7'] 

sE = ['-9,51', '-13,5', '0,193', '9,564', '23,13', '-0,252', '-0,442']
s = ['19,605', '28,388', '1,762', '-4,264', '-24,716', '-26,956', '0,382']
eE = ['-5,364', '-7,954', '-3,756', '-0,184', '1,883', '41,876', '-0,012']


X_axis = np.arange(len(X)) 

# plt.bar(X_axis, sE, color='red',width = 0.25, edgecolor='black') 
# plt.bar(X_axis+0.25, s, color='cyan',width = 0.25, edgecolor='black') 
# plt.bar(X_axis+0.5, eE, color='green',width = 0.25, edgecolor='black') 

#plt.hist([sE, s, eE], color = ['red', 'cyan', 'green'], edgecolor = 'black', histtype = 'bar')

#plt.xticks(X_axis, X) 
plt.xlabel("Classes")  
plt.title("Geographical STP A") 
plt.show()
```

But we're a long way from achieving the desired result. I really have no idea how to do this, can you help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to plot, the strings should be converted to numeric.

Plots with multiple bars per X-value are much easier using the Pandas (or Seaborn) library which builds on matplotlib for plotting. Your data doesn't have data for histogram, you seem to want a bar plot.

Here is some code. Many customizations are possible.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

X = ['Class 1', 'Class 2', 'Class 3', 'Class 4', 'Class 5', 'Class 6', 'Class 7']

sE = ['-9,51', '-13,5', '0,193', '9,564', '23,13', '-0,252', '-0,442']
s = ['19,605', '28,388', '1,762', '-4,264', '-24,716', '-26,956', '0,382']
eE = ['-5,364', '-7,954', '-3,756', '-0,184', '1,883', '41,876', '-0,012']

# organize the data as a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Class': X, 'sE': sE, 's': s, 'eE': eE})

# convert strings to numeric
df['sE'] = df['sE'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df['s'] = df['s'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)
df['eE'] = df['eE'].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

ax = df.set_index('Class').plot(kind='bar')

ax.set_title("Geographical STP A")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0)

plt.show()
```

[image: pandas bar plot]

Possible customizations could include:

```py
ax = df.set_index('Class').plot(kind='bar', color=['crimson', 'limegreen', 'dodgerblue'])

ax.set_title("Geographical STP A")
ax.tick_params(axis='x', rotation=0, length=0)  # rotate tick labels horizontally, remove tick mark
ax.grid(True, axis='y')  # add a grid in the y direction
ax.set_xlabel('')  # remove superfluous x label
for dir in ['top', 'bottom', 'right']:
    ax.spines[dir].set_visible(False)  # remove the border around the plot
```

[image: customized bar plot with pandas and matplotlib]

PS: The dataframe looks like:

| Class | sE | s | eE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class 1 | -9.51 | 19.605 | -5.364 |
| Class 2 | -13.5 | 28.388 | -7.954 |
| Class 3 | 0.193 | 1.762 | -3.756 |
| Class 4 | 9.564 | -4.264 | -0.184 |
| Class 5 | 23.13 | -24.716 | 1.883 |
| Class 6 | -0.252 | -26.956 | 41.876 |
| Class 7 | -0.442 | 0.382 | -0.012 |

Answer (score 1):

Making a grouped bar chart in pure `matplotlib` is a touch tedious, but you
can use the following pattern to do so.

Once you have the grouped chart, then you just need to adjust the plot
settings to fine-tune what you want:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

import numpy as np

X = ['Class 1','Class 2','Class 3','Class 4', 'Class 5', 'Class 6', 'Class 7']
data = {
    'eE': [-5.364, -7.954, -3.756, -0.184, 1.883, 41.876, -0.012],
    's' : [19.605, 28.388, 1.762, -4.264, -24.716, -26.956, 0.382],
    'sE': [-9.51, -13.5, 0.193, 9.564, 23.13, -0.252, -0.442],
}
palette = {'eE': 'red', 's': 'lime', 'sE': 'blue'}

plt.rc('font', size=14)

# construct grouped bar chart
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 7), layout='constrained')
xs = np.arange(len(X))
ngroups = len(data)

width = 1 / (ngroups + 1)
for multiplier, (label, values) in enumerate(data.items(), start=1):
    offset = width * multiplier
    ax.bar(xs + offset - .5, values, width * .9, label=label, edgecolor='k', color=palette[label])
ax.set_xticks(xs, labels=X)

# remove plot top, right, bottom plot border
ax.spines[['top', 'right', 'bottom']].set_visible(False)

# adjust x-tick labels & set grid
ax.xaxis.set_tick_params(which='both', rotation=90, bottom=False)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(1, offset=.5))
ax.xaxis.grid(visible=True, which='minor', linewidth=1.5)

# manually set y-tick labels & coerce border to only span the data limits
ticks = [
    y for y in ax.get_yticks()
    if ax.dataLim.y0 <= y <= ax.dataLim.y1
]
lower, upper = min(ticks), max(ticks)
ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(lower, upper)
ax.set_yticks(ticks)
ax.yaxis.grid(which='major', visible=True, ls='dotted')

# reduce padding on left/right and top/bottom of plotting area 
ax.margins(x=.01, y=0)

plt.show()
```

[image]